# read an empty file with fread

Tags: c, null, fread

I am trying to read an empty file with fread. Before i created the file with a blocksize of 4096 and an amount of 40 blocks. At the moment I know that these Blocks are "empty" but if i read the file like in my code below I cannot tell wether it is empty or not. I mean I am expecting nread to be NULL or something like that. 
Do you know what I have to compare nread with? Thank you!

```
int test()
{

   char buf[4096];
   FILE *file;
   size_t nread;

   file = fopen("out/abc.store", "r");
   if (file) {
       while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file)) > 0)
          fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
      if (ferror(file)) {
      /*error handling*/
   }
   fclose(file);
}
```

EDIT:

I created the file like that:

```
char *content=(char*)malloc(uintBlockSize*uintBlockCount);
memset(content,0,uintBlockSize*uintBlockCount);
...
 while (i!=0)
 {
   check=fwrite(content,uintBlockSize, 1, storeFile);
   if (check!=1)
       return 1;
   i--;
 }
```

Comment: If you created the file with a size greater than zero, it is not empty.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: tell me how i delete this question :D

Comment: There should be a delete link directly below the question.

Comment: Please don't vandalized your questions. If you want it deleted flag but give a *good* reason.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if `fread` returned 0. From the documentation ([here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/)):

> The total number of elements successfully read is returned.

Comment: :S i think i made a mistake with my question the file is not empty. But i created it like i wrote it in the edit.

Comment: It will not return zero.  It will return 4096 and it will do so 40 times.

Comment: i am sorry can i delete this question somehow?

Comment: @user2430568 - Yes, you can delete your own questions.  Or you can edit it to clarify your question.

Comment: so how can i delete it?

Answer (score -1):

fread will return the number of successfully read elements, so in this case, fread will return 0 (assuming it did not read anything), or EOF if it is the end.